# Make function callable with arguments

Tags: python

For my particular use case, I want to assign method2 without evaluating it and then want to call method1, like below.

```
class A():
    def method1(self):
        print("HELLO")
        return self

    def method2(self,arg1):
        print("HELLO"+arg1)
        return self  

a=A()
m2=a.method2

m2.method1()

m2("Peter")
```

When I do this I get that the function has no attribute method1.

How can I use method2 as a property with arguments?

Comment: what is the benefit of creating such awkward coupling between 2 different methods?

Comment: You can do it like you did. You just can't do `m2.method1()` because `method2` does not have `method1` inside it

Comment: If you did something like `A.method2.method1 = A.method1`, with the appropriate binding at runtime, this could work. Seems very odd though. It would make more sense to have another object which you can return from a `@property` `method2` which is both callable and has a `method1`.

Comment: you try to run `a.method2.method1()` which doesn't exist.

Comment: @deceze: Could you do an example?

Comment: What you did is completely fine and there is no need for `@property`s. If you want to call `method1` just change the line `m2.method1()` to `a.method1()`...

Comment: But I need to call method1 with m2. That is my question

Comment: So I must be able to use m2 without brackets, but also with brackets for an argument like "Peter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your specification…

```
a = A()
```

`A` must be a class (or at least callable which returns an object)…

```
m2 = a.method2
```

…which has an attribute `method2` which is/returns an object…

```
m2.method1()
```

…which has a callable `method1`…

```
m2("Peter")
```

…and is also callable itself.

Assuming that the object returned by `method2` is the same instance as `a`, this can be implemented like this:

```
class A:
    @property
    def method2(self):
        return self

    def method1(self):
        print('Hello')

    def __call__(self, name):
        print('Hello', name)
```

You could bend over backwards to make `method2` have an attribute `method1`, but for the behaviour you want this seems the most sensible. Alternatively instead of returning `self` in `method2` you may want to return some other object which has the same characteristics. And alternatively to implementing `method2` as a `@property`, you could just do `self.method2 = ...` in `__init__` instead.

Comment: So basically doing `m2 = a.method2` is just as doing `m2 = a`? Don't get me wrong, this is a great answer, I just still can't imagine the use-case...

Comment: Without a concrete use case this is all rather abstract anyway, yes. I'm mostly trying to disabuse OP of whatever corner they've painted themselves into and show that they should define the characteristics of the object first and then implement those characteristics as needed. Whatever actually makes sense in the end they need to decide.

Comment: @tado It makes your object *callable*. I.e. so you can do `m2()` instead of just being able to call a method on it like `m2.method()`.

Comment: I will try if it works and will come back later. But thank you!

Comment: @deceze : What do you mean by : ' And alternatively to implementing method2 as a property, you could just do self.method2 = ... in __init__ instead.'

Comment: @tado `def __init__(self): self.method2 = self`. That would have the same effect as the above `@property def method2(self): return self`.

Comment: Thanks you! And by the way it works perfect. That is nice, I never worked with property before.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially calling

```
m2 = a.method2.method1()

# but method2 has no method1.
```

If you would like to use method2, you can call using this

```
m2 = a.method2("Peter")
```

Comment: This is not completely accurate as there is nothing wrong with doing `m2("Peter")` as OP did since `m2` is simply binded to `method2`. The problem simply lays in trying to call `method1` through `method2` (which in this case is `m2`)